# How to select the scrollbar of a scrollable div, but not its `li` children or grandchildren

Tags: jquery

jQuery `:not(x)` ?

where x = a HTML element, e.g., `:not("li")`

Is this possible?

( the official jQuery docs talk about `:not(#id)` and `:not(.class)`, but but do not address `:not(markup)` ).

My goal = click the scrollbar, but not its `li` children or grandchildren:

[My scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBhhP.png)

This scrollbar has nothing but `li` children and grandchildren. So I figure that if I exclude these `li`, I am left with just the scrollbar.

Clicking the individual `$("li")` is covered elsewhere in my code. Here I want to be able to click on just the scrollbar for scrolling.

Currently, I have

```
const $MBScroller = $("#menubar");
```

But, what I really want is:

```
const $MBScroller = $("#menubar:not("li");  // or :not(li)
```

What"silly" thing am I not seeing?

Comment: Where is your working exemple ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want

```
#menubar *:not(li)
```

where the space indicates to select any descendent of the `#menubar`, and the `*` indicates to select any element, and the `:not(li)` indicates to exclude anything that's a `li`.

```
const $MBScroller = $("#menubar *:not(li)");
```

But a better approach would be to identify the element type of the scroller, and use that, eg

```
const $MBScroller = $("#menubar div");
```

or - the best approach - give it a class so that the selector is more specific and do

```
const $MBScroller = $("#menubar .scroller");
```

Comment: I thought :not(#id) and :not(.class) were okay, but not :not(markupElement) ??

Comment: `:not(SEL)` is permitted when `SEL` is a "simple selector". https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/selector.html#:~:text=A%20simple%20selector%20is%20either,what%20is%20used%20in%20CSS3.